# TOPdesk: accessing images directly for mail templates?

Tags: image, templates, server

I have an on-premise TOPdesk server running. I've created some e-mail templates to be used by TOPdesk when it sends e-mails to users.
These templates have the company logo in them, but somehow the logo's file becomes unavailable after some time. What I've noticed is that TOPdesk uses a unique ID to access the file, but this ID for some unknown reason changes. Perhaps due to a server restart and TOPdesk re-indexing the files.

In this case the file is available through the URL: `https://[topdesk_url]/tas/secure/mango/image?id=12345abcde`, so the e-mail template includes a reference to this image file: `<img src="https://[topdesk_url]/tas/secure/mango/image?id=12345abcde" alt="logo" />`. But when the ID changes I have to check the new ID and redo all the e-mail templates.

I'd like to know if there is a way to access this file directly without using the ID. Something like: `<img src="https://[topdesk_url]/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not too late to answer this. Your TOPdesk has a folder called 'web' and within that there is another folder called 'open'. Whatever you put in the there will be accessible. So for example if you put the 'logo.png' to the /web/open, then it will be accessible as https://[topdesk_url]/logo.png.